# Subsetting lists and looping through lists in R

Tags: r

I am running some analyses where I have to use a list of data frames as the input. The software uses lists of data sets as the output of conducting multiple imputation. However, I'd like to be able to automate some of the analyses. For example, here's some toy data to illustrate my issues:

```
a <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
c <- rep(c("a","b"),5)
data <- cbind.data.frame(a,b,c)
mylist <- list(data, data)
mylist
```

So `mylist` contains two data sets. These are the inputs for a Bayesian model I'm running using brms:

```
require(brms)
library(brms)
brm_multiple(a ~ b, data=mylist, cores =2)
```

Here, brms pools the posteriors from the multiple data sets. I have two questions:

1. How can I subset the lists so that the model is run only for rows of "a" for variable "c". That is, I want to fit the model `a ~ b` when `data$c == a`.
2. Next, is there a way I can loop through the values of variable "c" and store the estimates for each level of the variable? That is, automate the process so that I get `a ~ b` when `data$c == a`, and then when `data$c == b`, etc. and then save the estimates in a matrix?

Comment: Maybe 1) `data=lapply(mylist, subset, c == "a")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
c <- rep(c("a","b"),5)
data <- cbind.data.frame(a,b,c)
mylist <- list(data, data)
mylist



modelfunction <- function(dflist) {
  resultlist <- list()
  modelvars <- as.character(unique(dflist[[1]]$c))
  for(i in 1:length(modelvars)) {
    subsetdf <- lapply(dflist, function(x) x[x$c == modelvars[[i]], ])
    model <- brm_multiple(a ~ b, data=subsetdf, cores =2)
    resultlist[[i]] <- model 
  }
  return(resultlist)
}

modelfunction(mylist)
```

I wrote a function for you to to this. Subsets dynamically for each unique categorie in variable "c" in your list of data.frames and stores each model inside a list.